# Least squares coordinates when changing basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have two sets of $p$ vectors for a basis of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Arranging these vectors into matrices, I have $X$ and $Z$.  Each row of $Z$ can be obtained by a linear transformation of the  rows of $X$,  so

$$ Z = X \Omega $$

Suppose I solve a least squares problem using both $X$ and $Z$.  The corresponding coordinates of the solution in each basis might be $\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{w}$ respectively, so

$$ \hat{y} = X \hat{\beta} $$

$$ \hat{y} = Z \hat{w} $$

Because the bases are in general different from one another ($\Omega \neq I_p$), then $\hat{\beta} \neq \hat{w}$.  However, simple manipulation of the hat matrix yields that

$$ \hat{\beta} = \Omega \hat{w}$$

#### Question:

Why should this be the case?  Why are the least squares coordinates in the old basis simply the same transformation of the coordinates in the new basis?

Comment: Can you explain: "Suppose I solve a least squares problem "?